# If $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $g' \in L^p$ then $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} g(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am working on this problem from Le Gall's measure theory book with 2 parts.

1. Let $f$ be in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $1\leq p< \infty$. Let $q$ be the conjugate exponent of $p$. Let $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$. Verify that $F$ is well-defined and $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \lvert F(x+h) - F(x)\rvert}{h^{1/q}}= 0$$
2. Let $g$ be continuously differentiable and in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose $g' \in L^p$ for some $p \in [1, \infty)$. Then $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} g(x) = 0$.

I can show the first part using the density of continuous and compactly supported functions in $L^p$ but I need help with the second part. If I define $G(x) = \int_{0}^{x} g'(t)dt = g(x) - g(0)$ then the first part only gives me that $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\sup_{x} \lvert g(x+h) - g(x)\rvert}{h^{1/q}} = 0$$ This only gives a lipschitz like continuity bound and doesn't seem connected to the tails, at least on the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $g(x)$ does not tend to $0$ as $x \to \infty$. Then there is a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ and a positive number $\delta$ such that $|g(x_n)|>\delta$ for all $n$. Using the fact that  $\frac{\sup_{x} \lvert g(x+h) - g(x)\rvert}{h^{1/q}} \to 0$ conclude that there exists $h>0$ with the property $|g(x+h')-g(x)| <\delta/2$ for all $x$ whenever $0<h'<h$. Now $\int_{x_n}^{x_n+h} |g(y)|dy \ge \int_{x_n}^{x_n+h} [|g(x_n)|-\delta/2] dy>(\delta/2)h$ for all $n$. But integrability of $g$ implies that $\int_{x_n}^{\infty} |g(y)| dy \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$. We have arrived at a contradiction.

This proves that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)=0$. A similar argument shows that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you have to use the first part if $g' \in L^1$. As you have already mentioned in your question,
\begin{align}
g(x)=g(0) + \int_0^x g'(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \, .
\end{align}
Note that we can now pass to the limit as $x \to \infty$ (say by dominated convergence) to argue that the limit as $x \to +\infty$ exists and is given by
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = g(0) + \int_0^\infty g'(t)\, \mathrm{d}t \, .
\end{align}
Thus, $g$ has a limit as $x \to \infty$ (and $x \to -\infty$). It is then easy to see that it cannot be integrable unless the limit is $0$. if the limit were $a>0$ (w.l.o.g), then for $x$ larger than some $x_*$, we would have that $g (x) \in [a/2,3a/2]$ and thus
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |g| \, \mathrm{d}x \geq \int_{x_*}^\infty |g| \, \mathrm{d}x=+\infty \, ,
\end{align}
which is a contradiction.

Comment: It is not given that $g' \in L^{1}$. DCT not applicable to conclude that $\lim g(x)$ exists.

Comment: you are correct, I was too hasty this only works for $g' \in L^1$. I have edited the answer to indicate this.